# How to recieve microphone input with Speech Recognition in python properly

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition

I have a python program below. I want to take microphone input and get the text from the input. When I run the program, it always stops at line 9, "audio_text = r.listen(source)" and doesn't continue. It seems that it keeps waiting for microphone input to stop even though I have stopped talking. I know my microphone works because I recorded a file and played it back using aplay. Does anyone know why my program gets stuck at that line?

```
import speech_recognition as sr

print("Program has started!")

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Talk")
    audio_text = r.listen(source)
    print("Time over, thanks")
    
    try:
        # using google speech recognition
        print("Text: "+r.recognize_google(audio_text))
    except:
         print("Sorry, I did not get that")
```

I am running this on Raspberry pi os and using python3.

Answer (score 0):

try adding these line to stop the recording if your mic doesn't stop listening

```
  Stop_listening=r.listen_in_background(source,callback)
  Stop_listening(wait_to_stop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried that but it still didnt work. I found an alternate solution which I am using for my program. Instead of recording directly from the microphone and using the live audio, I am instead recording short intervals of audio through the mic. Then I am using the audio files to generate text. Thank you anyways. :)